# Audiofiles are played with wrong speed

Tags: c#, naudio

I am using NAudio in a C#-Application and my problem is, that the playback speed depends on the sampling rate. I used two Wav files that contain a 1000Hz sin wave with either Fs = 44100Hz and Fs = 88200 Hz. I checked the output signal of my soundcard with an oscilloscope. It turns out that my file with Fs = 44100 is over after half the expected time, whereas the output frequency is doubled (2kHz). When using the files in other players (e.g. windows media player, audacity) everything looks fine. When debugging I looked into the waveformat of these files and everything looked fine as well. I also varied the bit resolution resulting in no difference. I am not sure if i am just missing out of something.

I use this in another program where this problem first occured. Therefore I made a small rudimentary programm to see if I already made a mistake in my bigger application, the same problem exists there aswell.

It would be really great and highly appreciated, if someone could help me.
Kind regards
Leo

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using NAudio.Wave;

namespace WindowsFormsApp2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        AsioOut asioOut;
        AudioFileReader afr4;
        AudioFileReader afr8;
        AudioFileReader afr0;
        MixingWaveProvider32 mwp;

        int playingID = 0;
        int channelID;
        Boolean audioplaying = false;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            asioOut = new AsioOut();
            afr4 = new AudioFileReader("../wavs/sin1000Hz_1.75s_16bit_44100Hz_ramp50ms.wav");
            afr8 = new AudioFileReader("../wavs/sin1000Hz_1.75s_16bit_88200Hz_ramp50ms.wav");
            afr0 = new AudioFileReader("../wavs/sin14607Hz_180sec_20msRamp_fs96000_24bit_mono_doppelt.wav");
            mwp  = new MixingWaveProvider32();



            afr4.Volume = 1.0f;
            afr8.Volume = 1.0f;

            for (int i = 0; i < asioOut.DriverOutputChannelCount; i++) {
                Console.WriteLine(i + ": " + asioOut.AsioOutputChannelName(i));
                if (asioOut.AsioOutputChannelName(i).Equals("Analog 3 (1)")) {
                    channelID = i;
                }
            }
            asioOut.ChannelOffset = channelID;
            asioOut.Init(mwp);
            asioOut.PlaybackStopped += OnPlaybackStopped;
        }

        //a button to play the Fs = 44100Hz File
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (audioplaying == false) {
                mwp.AddInputStream(afr4);
                afr4.Position = 0;

                audioplaying = true;
                playingID = 4;

                asioOut.Play();
            }           
        }

        //a button to play the Fs = 88200Hz File
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (audioplaying == false) {
                mwp.AddInputStream(afr8);
                afr8.Position = 0;

                audioplaying = true;
                playingID = 8;

                asioOut.Play();
            }
        }

        //a button to play just another audiofile
        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (audioplaying == false) {
                mwp.AddInputStream(afr0);
                afr0.Position = 0;

                audioplaying = true;
                playingID = 0;

                asioOut.Play();
            }
        }

        //after playback every Input gets removed again to setup for new playback
        protected virtual void OnPlaybackStopped(object sender, EventArgs e) {            
            if (playingID == 4) {
                mwp.RemoveInputStream(afr4);
            } else if (playingID == 8) {
                mwp.RemoveInputStream(afr8);
            } else {
                mwp.RemoveInputStream(afr0);
            }
            audioplaying = false;

        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            asioOut.Stop();
        }       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `MixingWaveProvider32` to mix together streams with different `WaveFormat`. You need to pick a single `WaveFormat` and pass that into the constructor. You should then only add items that have that `WaveFormat` although `MixingWaveProvider32` isn't enforcing that when you only have one item at a time like you are doing

Comment: Worked out for me. Thanks for your advice.